# Dados geográficos

Tags: c#, .net

Quais são as classes .net para trabalhar com dados geográficos (latitude, longitude, etc)?
Durante uma pesquisa encontrei o *namespace* `System.Spatial` mas vi em um fórum alguém desaconselhando o seu uso por ser obsoleto. Olhando a doc desse *namespace* vi que a maioria de suas classes são classes abstratas.
Eu tenho um projeto onde para várias classes *Model* eu preciso ter uma propriedade que representará a localização geográfica. Por exemplo, para uma classe `Cliente` eu terei uma propriedade chamada *Localização* que armazenará uma coordenada geográfica (latitude e longitude). Eu pensei em criar um tipo `Coordenada`, uma classe simples com duas propriedades onde uma seria a latitude e longitude, mas pensei que pode já existir algo pronto e mais sofisticado.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Spatial/